# 2020 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Sports's [first moderator election](https://sports.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the three new moderators are:

[image: Joe] [image: Philip Kendall] [image: Nij]

They'll be your first elected moderators since you lost your "beta" label last year. Please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Let's also take a moment to thank [the previous team who've served you as pro-tems](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120/moderator-pro-tem-announcement) while your site was still in beta.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://sports.stackexchange.com/election/1), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5645641495609344/0).

Answer (score 11):

Thanks to everyone for voting - the activity is great to see!  Congratulations to my fellow moderators Nij and Philip.  Dly and Olaf, I hope to see you around doing all the great moderating you're already doing - 90% of the work is done by the community, not the diamond moderators, and I'm sure your turn will come!

Answer (score 10):

Thank you to the community for the vote of confidence. While I'm here, please everyone extend a big thank you to our retiring moderators, [jamauss](https://sports.stackexchange.com/users/18/jamauss) and [Michael Myers](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/a/980/6126), and also to our long-term moderator, [ᴍᴀsᴛᴇʀᴍɪɴᴅ_ᴇᴅ](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/a/966/6126), who stepped down in 2017.

Joe and Nij you I look forward to working with you in the future, and to dly and Ola I echo Joe's comments hoping that you stay and continue to contribute to the site in the way you have been doing.

Answer (score 7):

Thank you, everybody.

Those who ran, it was pleasing to see such a comparatively broad range of users stepping up to the plate.

Those who voted, it gives me confidence that we remain engaged in our small corner of the Stack Exchange world, and that the community is happy with the directions it's going.

Those who have and are moderating, I hope I can uphold the high standard of stewardship you've applied for the rest of us. I look forward to making the most of what I have learned so far and will learn in time to come.